# Define using toExponentional() when a number has X numbers of digit in JS

Tags: javascript, function, math, numbers

So this is the case, I want to transform a number into Scientific (Exponentional) notation after my number has for example, 4 digits (so 0.001 is 1.00e-3 and 574635 is 5.75e5)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential 5secs googling.

Comment: @JonasW. I think the OP knows about `toExponential` (that's why they mentioned it in the title) but they want to conditionally use it (or not) based on the number of digits in the number.

Comment: You mention "4 digits" in your question body, but "X" digits in your title. The four is just an example, and you actually want a function of the form `exponentialIfEnoughDigits(number, digitThreshold)` correct?

Comment: @apsillers yes, this is exactly what I want, if the number has X digits then format, otherwise leave the number...

Answer (score 1):

```
  const format = n => ("" + n).length > 4 ? n.toExponential() : n;
```